# For each span with class X find the label in the td before it and insert the label after the span with class X

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to move the label inside of each `td.donationField` after the nearest `span.givingAmount.radioLabel`.

The html is hard code so I cannot move things around manually  so it has to be done using a script.

Here is what I tried, having trouble selecting up the DOM

```js
$('span.givingAmount.radioLabel').each(function(){
            $(this).closest('td').contents('label').insertAfter(this);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
<td class="donationField">
<span class="vaTop" itemindex="26" amount="1000"><input id="2142_rdo_26_4" type="radio" name="givingLevels" value="rdo_26_4" onclick="rdo_OnClick(this);"><label for="2142_rdo_26_4"> Description goes here</label></span>
</td>
<td class="controlField">
<span class="givingAmount radioLabel">$ 1,000.00 </span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="donationField">
<span class="vaTop" itemindex="26" amount="1000"><input id="2142_rdo_26_4" type="radio" name="givingLevels" value="rdo_26_4" onclick="rdo_OnClick(this);"><label for="2142_rdo_26_4">2nd Description</label></span>
</td>
<td class="controlField">
<span class="givingAmount radioLabel">$ 2,000.00 </span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does the relocation you what you want

```js
$('.donationField label').each(function() {
  $(this).closest('td').next().append(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="donationField">
      <span class="vaTop" itemindex="26" amount="1000"><input id="2142_rdo_26_4" type="radio" name="givingLevels" value="rdo_26_4" onclick="rdo_OnClick(this);">
      
      <label for="2142_rdo_26_4"> Description goes here</label></span>
    </td>
    <td class="controlField">
      <span class="givingAmount radioLabel">$ 1,000.00 </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="donationField">
      <span class="vaTop" itemindex="26" amount="1000"><input id="2142_rdo_26_4" type="radio" name="givingLevels" value="rdo_26_4" onclick="rdo_OnClick(this);"><label for="2142_rdo_26_4">2nd Description</label></span>
    </td>
    <td class="controlField">
      <span class="givingAmount radioLabel">$ 2,000.00 </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```